# Eclipse Indigo 3.7.2 - paste removes tabs and whitespace

Tags: eclipse, copy-paste, eclipse-indigo

I am using Eclipse 3.7.2, with PDT (on Windows 7) and lately when pasting indented text (space or tabs) from Eclipse or from outside, all the tabs / whitespace gets completely removed.

Anybody else had this problem?

Comment: I have the same problem. "Java -> Editor -> Save Ations" are disabled for the project and for the workspace, but it doesn't help. First I thought that it could be the installation of Checkstyle plugin. I uninstalled it, but it didn't help either.

Comment: I have this same issue in Eclipse Mars.1

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was in configuration of "AnyEdit Tools". The option "Remove trailing whitespace" was checked. But I remember that I have never changed the options of this plugin. Mystic. Have no idea how the configuration was changed. Maybe the installation of another plugin did this change...

But however the unchecking of this option has helped.